# Trying to buy NFT on Binance marketplace using Python requests, can't pass recaptcha

Tags: python, python-requests, recaptcha, binance, nft

The task is to buy an NFT item on the Binance NFT market (https://www.binance.com/en/nft/blindBox/market?theme=126206614880739328).

NFT item page example -  https://www.binance.com/ru/nft/goods/blindBox/detail?productId=7120324&isOpen=false&isProduct=1

I am using Python requests to send a post request. If I click on the buy button and confirm the purchase, then a post request send to recaptcha.net
[image]

For "order-create" request (on the image above) I need a key received in response from a recaptcha request.

How can I pass captcha?

Comment: you need to use Binance API for that

Comment: Binance does not have an official API for the NFT Market

Comment: Bad news... re-capture is a very hard problem. So there is no simple solution here because it has regular updates and even if you find some code here or on Github, it will fail in 99%.

Comment: You're looking for a captcha bypass. Unfortunately there is no long-term code solution for that. Try [Amazon Mechanical Turk](https://www.mturk.com/) to crowdsource your captcha solving.

Comment: Use one of these services: 2captcha, capmonster cloud, deathbycaptcha